# How do I backup a directory using bash script

Tags: linux, bash, redhat

I am having difficulty trying to backup my 'my_work' directory into my destination 'Backup' directory. I tried running the script, but it does not seem to work. This is the script that I have written :

```
#!/bin/bash

SRCDIR="/home/student/Documents/my_work/"
DESTDIR="/home/student/Backups/"
FILENAME=backup1-$(date +%-Y%-m%-d)-$(date +%-T).tgz 
tar --create --gzip --file=$DESTDIR $FILENAME $SRCDIR
```

This is the output I received :

```
tar: backup1-201576-10\:24\:17.tgz: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Removing leading '/' from member names
tar (child): /home/student/Backups/: Cannot open: Is a directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

I can't seem to find a solution to this, please help

Comment: possibly related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46969/compress-a-folder-with-tar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make a subtle change in your script:

Change

`tar --create --gzip --file=$DESTDIR $FILENAME $SRCDIR`

to

`tar --create --gzip --file=$DESTDIR$FILENAME $SRCDIR`

Notice there is no space between `$DESTDIR` and `$FILENAME`. To suppress `tar: Removing leading '/' from member names`, you may use the [`-P` flag cautiously](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59243/tar-removing-leading-from-member-names).

Also, it'd be nice to replace colons in the filename with underscores or dashes. Colon is a reserved character that is also used in `PATH` and may cause confusion.

Comment: Suggesting quotes around the variable expansions would also be a good idea.